# Как менять размеры ConstraintLayout во время работы приложения?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Мне нужно при определённом условии убирать (height = 0) дочерний ConstraintLayout, а потом вновь показывать (height = match_constraint). Пробовал так:

Убрать:

```
val c = ConstraintSet()
            c.clone(constraintLayoutTable)
            c.constrainMaxHeight(R.id.constraintLayoutTableTitle, 0)
            c.constrainPercentHeight(R.id.constraintLayoutTableTitle, 0.0f)
            c.applyTo(constraintLayoutTable)
```

Вернуть:

```
 val c = ConstraintSet()
            c.clone(constraintLayoutTable)
            c.constrainHeight(R.id.constraintLayoutTableTitle, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT)
            c.constrainMaxHeight(R.id.constraintLayoutTableTitle, 100)
            c.constrainPercentHeight(R.id.constraintLayoutTableTitle, 100.0f)
            c.applyTo(constraintLayoutTable)
```

Вышеперечисленные методы не работают.

Разметка элемента constraintLayoutTableTitle:

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutTableTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="I"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="I" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: вам будет интересно узнать, что [значение константы](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#MATCH_CONSTRAINT) `ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT` = 0 (dp) ...

Comment: значение 0dp в констрайнт лэйаут значит, что виджет должен занимать всю доступную ширину/высоту родителя(аналог match_parent). для того, чтобы скрыть/показать элемент используются атрибуты View.VISIBLE, View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что размеры констрайнта не работают без привязки.
Из вашего кода не совсем понятно, есть ли у элемента привязка к чему либо. Вот пример изменения констрайнта с изменением размера:

```
// current constraint
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

// copy constraints settings from current ConstraintLayout to set
set.clone(constraintLayout);

// change what you want
set.connect(/* your connect */);
set.constrainWidth(/* your element */, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

// enable animation if needed
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);

// apply constraints settings from set to current ConstraintLayout
set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Получится примерно вот так:

[image: constraint]

Подробнее вы можете посмотреть, например, [вот здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/494-urok-183-constraintset-programmnaya-nastroyka-constraintlayout.html).

Надеюсь, эта ифномация поможет вам. Happy coding!

Comment: Добавил разметку элемента в вопрос. У элемента есть привязки